# Excluding Products from Coupon by Category

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules

If a product is in categories 14 and 156 and I exclude category 14 (see settings below) from the coupon will that product still be able to be purchased using the coupon if the customer shopped it from category 156?

My confusion is due to what's being said within the "Actions" tab:

> "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions"
>
> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE:
>
> Category is not 14

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter from which category the product has been browsed, this information is not part of the quote, so the shopping cart price rules cannot take it into account.

The condition means: "If the product is **not assigned to category 14**"

Which does not match a product that is in category 14 and 156.